# Чем отличается режим браузера и документов в ie?

Tags: internet-explorer

Всем привет! Хотелось бы задать вопрос касающийся версий браузера IE, а именно режима браузера в IE и режим документов IE. Чем они отличаются? И какую именно функцию надо использовать, чтоб проверить страницу в 7 или 8 версии браузера?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Войти в IE, зайти на интересующую страницу, нажать F12, переключить "режим браузера" на 7 или 8.

Comment: а за что отвечает режим документа? стоит ли его трогать что-та менять когда меняешь версию браузера?